# How this Python generators based inorder traversal method works

Tags: python

I am quite new to python and still exploring. Came across generators and below code snippet implementing inorder binary tree traversal using generators:

```
def inorder(t):
    if t:
        for x in inorder(t.left):
            yield x

        yield t.label

        for x in inorder(t.right):
            yield x
```

Now I know following fact about generators: they remember the local variable values across calls. However this function is recursive. So how it remembers local variable values across these different recursive calls?

Also it was easy to understand normal recursive inorder program (not involving generators) as there were clear recursion termination conditions explicitly specified. But how this recursion with generators works?

Answer (score 2):

`inorder` returns a generator. *That* object is what remembers its local state between calls to `next`. There is no overlap between generators created by separate calls to `inorder`, even when called recursively.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code somewhat to get the idea of the flow of the execution sequence. Basically I added some `print()` statements.

```
class BinaryTreeNode():
    def __init__(self, pLeft, pRight, pValue):
        self.left = pLeft
        self.right = pRight
        self.label = pValue

def inorder(t):
    print("at the beginning of inorder(t): " + (str(t.label) if t else "None" ))
    if t:
        for x in inorder(t.left):
            print("inside inorder(t.left):" + str(t.label))   #delete
            yield x

        print("inside inorder(t):" + str(t.label))   #delete
        yield t.label

        for x in inorder(t.right):
            print("inside inorder(t.right):" + str(t.label))  #delete
            yield x

node1 = BinaryTreeNode(None,None,1)
node3 = BinaryTreeNode(None,None,3)
node2 = BinaryTreeNode(node1,node3,2)
node5 = BinaryTreeNode(None,None,5)
node4 = BinaryTreeNode(node2,node5,4)

root = node4

for i in inorder(root):
    print(i)
```

The output is:

```
1    at the beginning of inorder(t): 4
2    at the beginning of inorder(t): 2
3    at the beginning of inorder(t): 1
4    at the beginning of inorder(t): None
5    inside inorder(t):1
6    inside inorder(t.left):2
7    inside inorder(t.left):4
8    1
9    at the beginning of inorder(t): None
10    inside inorder(t):2
11    inside inorder(t.left):4
12    2
13    at the beginning of inorder(t): 3
14    at the beginning of inorder(t): None
15    inside inorder(t):3
16    inside inorder(t.right):2
17    inside inorder(t.left):4
18    3
19    at the beginning of inorder(t): None
20    inside inorder(t):4
21    4
22    at the beginning of inorder(t): 5
23    at the beginning of inorder(t): None
24    inside inorder(t):5
25    inside inorder(t.right):4
26    5
27    at the beginning of inorder(t): None
```

Notice that second call to `inorder(node4)` didnt print `at the beginning of inorder(t): 4` but it printed `at the beginning of inorder(t): None` (line 9 in output). That means generators also remembers the last executed line (mostly because it remembers program counter value in the last call).

Also every for loop obtains generator instance from the function `inorder()`. This generator is specific to for loop and hence there local scope is maintained separately.

Above traverses this tree:

```
    4
   / \
  2   5
 / \
1   3
```

Also the termination occurs when each of the recursive calls reach to its end. This result in following recursive call tree:

```
==>inorder(<4>) 
   |---> x in inorder(left<2>)
                 |---> x in inorder(left<1>)
                               |---> x in inorder(left<None>) --> terminate
                                    yield 1   (note the indention, it is not yield inside first for-in loop but after it)
                            yield 1  (note the indentation, this is yield inside first for-in loop)
              yield 1



inorder(<4>)
   |---> x in inorder(left<2>)
                 |---> x in inorder(left<1>)        
==============================>|---> x in inorder(right<None>) --> terminate
                      yield 2
              yield 2



inorder(<4>)
   |---> x in inorder(left<2>)
================>|---> x in inorder(right<3>)                                                      
                               |---> x in inorder(left<None>) --> terminate
                                     yield 3  
                            yield 3
              yield 3     



inorder(<4>)
  |---> x in inorder(left<2>)
                |---> x in inorder(left<1>)        
=============================>|---> x in inorder(right<None>) --> terminate
                      terminate
             terminate
        yield 4



inorder(4)
==>|---> x in inorder(right<5>)
                 |---> x in inorder(left<None>) --> terminate
                       yield 5 
              yield 5


inorder(4)
   |---> x in inorder(right<5>)                 
===============>|---> x in inorder(right<None>) --> terminate
                      terminate
              terminate
         terminate
```

(explaination:

- `<i>` means call with `nodei` as parameter
- `left<i>` represents `inorder(t.left)` call inside first `for-in` loop where `t.left` is `nodei`
- `right<i>` represents `inorder(t.right)` call inside second `for-in` loop where `t.right` is `nodei`
- `===>` shows where execution begins in that particular call)